# Error while query druid using sql like in ()

Tags: sql, druid

Query druid using the sql below

```
SELECT CASE WHEN sale_mode in (1,2,3)  THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END AS type
FROM "20051001"
WHERE __time>'2018-04-22 00:00:00'
```

and return the following error message

```
Bad Request: Unknown exception: Error while applying rule 
DruidQueryRule:SELECT_PROJECT, args [rel#103796215:LogicalProject.NONE.[] 
(input=rel#103796209:Subset#6.NONE.[],type=CASE(OR(=($45, '1'), =($45, '2'), 
=($45, '3')), 'a', 'b')), rel#103796236:DruidQueryRel.NONE.[[]](query= 
{"queryType":"scan","dataSource": 
{"type":"table","name":"20051001"},"intervals": 
{"type":"intervals","intervals":["2018-04-21T16:00:00.001Z/146140482-04- 
24T15:36:27.903Z"]},"virtualColumns" [],"resultFormat":"compactedList","batchSize":20480,"limit":9223372036854775807,"filter":null,"columns":
```

But if I  "CASE WHEN sale_mode in (1,2,3) " to "CASE WHEN sale_mode in (1,2) ", it works, so what if the problem, anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Is `20051001` actually the name of one of your tables?  That looks like a string literal to me.

Comment: yes, it is the table